# Converting 12 hr to 24 hr python shows 24:00:00 as 24:00:00 and not 00:00:00

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

when i used the following code. I do understand that i am adding 12 to the time given and it returns 24:00:00 but i am not able to understand how to get 00:00:00.

My timestamp has list of time values.

```
r = timestamp[:-2] if timestamp[-2:] == "AM" else str(int(timestamp[:2]) + 12) + timestamp[2:8]
```

Comment: Why don't you use the proper way of achieving this? (ie the `datetime` module).

Comment: Have you tried using [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module?

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo arithmetic to divide by 24 and get the remainder. Change this:

```
int(timestamp[:2]) + 12
```

to this:

```
(int(timestamp[:2]) + 12) % 24
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> 12 + 12
24
>>> (12 + 12) % 24
0
```

Comment: It gives out 0 and not 00 i believe.

Comment: 0 and 00 are the same number. If you want to pad the result to two digits, use string formatting of some kind, e.g. `str(hour).rjust(2, '0')`.